# quanteda collocations and lemmatization

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda, collocation

I am using the **Quanteda suite of packages** to preprocess some text data. I want to incorporate collocations as features and decided to use the **textstat_collocations** function. According to the documentation and I quote:

"*The tokens object .  . . . **While identifying collocations for tokens objects is supported, you will get better results with character or corpus objects** due to relatively imperfect detection of sentence boundaries from texts already tokenized.*"

This makes perfect sense, so here goes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textstats)

# Some sample data and lemmas
df= c("this column has a lot of missing data, 50% almost!",
                   "I am interested in missing data problems",
                   "missing data is a headache",
                   "how do you handle missing data?")

lemmas <- data.frame() %>%
    rbind(c("missing", "miss")) %>%
    rbind(c("data", "datum")) %>%
    `colnames<-`(c("inflected_form", "lemma"))
```

(1) Generate collocations using the corpus object:

```
txtCorpus = corpus(df)
docvars(txtCorpus)$text <- as.character(txtCorpus)
myPhrases = textstat_collocations(txtCorpus, tolower = FALSE)
```

(2) preprocess text and identify collocations and lemmatize for downstream tasks.

```
# I used a blank space as concatenator and the phrase function as explained in the documentation and I followed the multi multi substitution example in the documentation
# https://quanteda.io/reference/tokens_replace.html
txtTokens = tokens(txtCorpus, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, 
                               remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_tolower() %>%
    tokens_compound(pattern = phrase(myPhrases$collocation), concatenator = " ") %>%
    tokens_replace(pattern=phrase(c(lemmas$inflected_form)), replacement=phrase(c(lemmas$lemma)))
```

(3) test results

```
# Create dtm
dtm = dfm(txtTokens, remove_padding = TRUE)

# pull features
dfm_feat = as.data.frame(featfreq(dtm)) %>%
    rownames_to_column(var="feature") %>%
    `colnames<-`(c("feature", "count"))

dfm_feat
```

| feature | count |
| --- | --- |
| this | 1 |
| column | 1 |
| has | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| lot | 1 |
| of | 1 |
| almost | 1 |
| i | 2 |
| am | 1 |
| interested | 1 |
| in | 1 |
| problems | 1 |
| is | 1 |
| headache | 1 |
| how | 1 |
| do | 1 |
| you | 1 |
| handle | 1 |
| **missing data** | 4 |

"*missing data*" should be "*miss datum*".

This is only works if each document in df is a single word. I can make the process work if I generate my collocations using a token object from the get-go but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have already compounded the elements of the collocations into a single "token" containing a space, but by supplying the `phrase()` wrapper in `tokens_compound()`, you are telling `tokens_replace()` to look for two sequential tokens, not the one with a space.

The way to get what you want is by making the lemmatised replacement match the collocation.

```r
phrase_lemmas <- data.frame(
  inflected_form = "missing data",
  lemma = "miss datum"
)
tokens_replace(txtTokens, phrase_lemmas$inflected_form, phrase_lemmas$lemma)
## Tokens consisting of 4 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1 :
## [1] "this"       "column"     "has"        "a"          "lot"       
## [6] "of"         "miss datum" "almost"    
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "i"          "am"         "interested" "in"         "miss datum"
## [6] "problems"  
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "miss datum" "is"         "a"          "headache"  
## 
## text4 :
## [1] "how"        "do"         "you"        "handle"     "miss datum"
```

Alternatives would be to use `tokens_lookup()` on uncompounded tokens directly, if you have a fixed listing of sequences you want to match to lemmatised sequences.  E.g.,

```r
tokens(txtCorpus) %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary(list("miss datum" = "missing data")),
    exclusive = FALSE, capkeys = FALSE
  )
## Tokens consisting of 4 documents and 1 docvar.
## text1 :
##  [1] "this"       "column"     "has"        "a"          "lot"       
##  [6] "of"         "miss datum" ","          "50"         "%"         
## [11] "almost"     "!"         
## 
## text2 :
## [1] "I"          "am"         "interested" "in"         "miss datum"
## [6] "problems"  
## 
## text3 :
## [1] "miss datum" "is"         "a"          "headache"  
## 
## text4 :
## [1] "how"        "do"         "you"        "handle"     "miss datum"
## [6] "?"
```

Comment: Hi Ken & thank you for your answer. The challenge with this approach is that I have a large df of lemmas (single words) and their replacements just as in the example. The collocations can be any combination of them. Are you suggesting I should construct a list of inflected_forms & lemmas specifically for the collocations using pattern matching?

Comment: Then you could replace them prior to compounding and then compound the lemmas.

Comment: Thanks again Ken. That's what I ended up doing. It wasn't so straight forward for me. I separated the collocations into two columns (I only need 2) and then tokenized and did token_replace on each column. I then pasted back the words. This was pretty quick. String based functions would be another option but I get weird results.